# Factory Method Pattern trouble

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have read Factory Method pattern. I have a problem when design the latter example.

Best design for the pattern? Anybody can give me any suggestions?

```
     AbstractProduct                   Creator
         /     \                        /   \
    Product1 Product2             Creator1 Creator2



        AbstractProduct                         ? How to design Creator ?
       /     |         \
Product1 Product2 SubAbstractProduct
                       /     \
                  Product3 Product 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Creator* can be designed the same way as in the previous example because Concrete Creators that create *Product3* and *Product4* still are *AbstractProduct*.

Answering the comment:

Not really. When this *AbstractProduct createProduct()* is overridden in child Concrete Creator classes (which is the factory pattern), it can return *SubAbstractProduct*.

Just wanted to add that you can do the above (i.e. overridden method returning a subtype of what is returned in the parent class method)in java since Java 1.5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if Creator have a method: _AbstractProduct createProduct()_, then when I use _product = createProduct()_ so product is just AbstractProduct type, not SubAbstractProduct, product can't use any extended method from SubAbstractProduct.

Comment: OK, but if SubAbstractProduct has a method that AbstractProduct hasn't, *moreMethod()* for example. While *product* is just AbstractProduct, so if it want to use *moreMethod()*, I have to type cast.